# Sending emails with multiple attachments to multiple recipients

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found a code online that sends emails to multiple recipients that attaches one file per email.

I want to go to a specific folder, attach all PDF files in the folder then go to a different folder and do the same for the next email recipient.

The image shows the structure of the sheet. I'm using Office 365.
[image]

```vb
Sub SendMail()

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    On Error GoTo MyHandler

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A2000")

        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        With objMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Cc = "email@email.com"
            .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Body = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Display
        End With

        Set objMail = Nothing
    Next cell

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

MyHandler:
    MsgBox "Review email messages"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to repeat the `Attachment.Add` method for each file in a folder:

```
Sub SendMail()

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim StrFile As String, StrPath As String

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

On Error GoTo MyHandler

For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A2000")

   Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
        .To = cell.Value
        .Cc = "email@email.com"
        .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .Body = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    End With

        StrPath = "D:\any_folder\" 
        StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.*")

        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            objMail.Attachments.Add StrPath & StrFile
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop  

    objMail.Display

    Set objMail = Nothing
Next cell

 Set ws = Nothing
 Set objOutlook = Nothing

MyHandler:
  MsgBox "Review email messages"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm getting a compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference at the attachment line.

Comment: I have just corrected the source code. You need to specify the parent object.

Comment: What it does now is to get all the files from the root folder C:\Temp\. How can I make it sort thru the folders specified in column D and get the files from there?

I changed the StrPath as below.

StrPath = "C:\TEMP\"

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice:

```
Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

Comment: Thanks, found that as well before but problem is I would need to specify each file which becomes very tedious if you are working in volume. Say you're working for 200 different folders with some folders having 18 files in them, I would need to type each path & filename.

Comment: Wow.  With that in mind, I don't think Excel is the right tool for this kind of job.  You would have to do some pretty advanced VBA coding to get all files and file paths setup correctly, according to whatever logic you are using.  How would you even audit, or reconcile, this kind of tool?